# Adding apostrophe/single quote to my RegEx match

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm using `[A-Za-z0-9_-]` to match letters, numbers and _ and - in my regular expression.
I'd like to add the `'` character to it but most of my attempts result in server error 500.

Here's the full line from my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+/?$ /index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried escaping it with \?

Comment: A rule like: `RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\']+/?$ /index.php` should work.

Comment: Might be because the - in a character class has special meaning, try putting that in front. `RewriteRule ^[-a-zA-Z0-9_']+/?$ /index.php` Right now you're saying match from the character _ to the character \ which doesn't really make sense.